# How to fix chimney hole in roof?

Tags: insulation, roof, chimney, hole, hole-repair

I've starting insulating the roof and that got me looking at the "old" hole where a (useless) chimney used to be. That chimney got removed for a solar panel setup.

As I'm insulating, this needs to be closed off from the weather entirely. I just have no idea on how to approach this.

What can you see (in order top to bottom) in the picture:

1. red roof tile (they did a shit job "closing" the hole left by the removed chimney) - will be writing them to come fix that as it just lets air in
2. some sort of mashed wood, possibly plywood (on top of which are horizontal strips of wood as braces for tiles)
3. 80's roof insulation
4. mashed wood sheets

The brighter yellow is a filler foam that was around the chimney.

The new-looking wood bit is a small piece of plywood they (didn't) cover the whole hole with (and I now can't get to due to solar installation on top of it).

**Can I fix this from the inside to be isolated from the weather? How to do so?**

[image]
[image]

- Sizes are in centimeters
- Apologies for names of things, no idea what the names are of something like "mashed wood sheet" in English
- Also no idea if this would be the place to ask, but StackExchange doesn't seem to have another site for this, didn't think the wood-working one was a good fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should really be fixed from the outside first and an appropriate water barrier placed over the hole. If your only concern is closing the hole you could simply cut out a piece of plywood (mashed wood) to fit the whole and then use one or two small strips of wood to screw that piece into the surrounding wood. Something similar to the below:

[image]

Then fill the cracks with a foam. However, all this would do is seal the hole from any real air flow, but would leave a potential problem for leaks if any water was to get under the tiles. As such it is really recommended to get who ever fixed the tiles to come back and do things properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have written (today) the company that they've done a shoddy job of things, so will wait for them for a bit for a fix from the outside (waterproofing & covering the hole). Assuming that happens/gets done soon, I'm still left wondering about how then to fix the hole. Fill it with foam, then cut a piece to close it off smooth before insulating as per the rest of the roof? Also, it will have to be that company that fixes teh outside, there's a solar panel and transformer setup on the outside on top of the roof tiles above the hole.

Comment: Once it is properly sealed from the outside it is up to you if you want to go through the process of also sealing it from the inside. If you are going to put insulation over it anyway you could just skip the step of sealing it from the inside, but otherwise yes filling it with foam and then covering the part that is cut out should work.